# Bitbucket pipeline fails - even on a single script like Echo

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to use bitbucket pipeline with Windows runner.

I have stripped the complete build steps down a single item

echo $env:SOLUTION_NAME

and it still fails

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        runs-on:
          - self.hosted
          - windows
        name: Lint the code
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:              
          - echo $env:SOLUTION_NAME
```

[image]

As suggested I added **exit 0** - makes no difference - just fails on that line now.  I have never had a successful build.

[image]

Comment: the pipeline fails if the exit code is not 0. Try with `exit 0` as the last command?

Comment: I added exit 0 but it just fails on that line now - see original text I added a new image there.

Comment: I removed the following and the script now executes without error.

 caches:           
   - dotnetcore